# Mismo valor dos celdas de Google Sheets

Tags: excel, script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo dos hojas en Google Sheets. ¿Es posible igualar siempre dos celdas? Por ejemplo Hoja1!A1 con Hoja2!A1 de tal forma que si cambio el valor en Hoja1!A1 se cambie el valor en Hoja2!A1 y si cambio el valor en Hoja2!A1 se cambie en Hoja1!A1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con el siguiente script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Hojas que deseas conectar
  let hoja1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Hoja 1');
  let hoja2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Hoja 2');
  
  // Hoja activa
  let sheetName =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
  
  // Valor de entrada
  let inputValue = e.value

  if(e.range.getA1Notation() === 'A1' && hoja1.getSheetName() == sheetName){
    hoja2.getRange('A1').setValue(inputValue);
  }

  if(e.range.getA1Notation() === 'A1' && hoja2.getSheetName() == sheetName){
    hoja1.getRange('A1').setValue(inputValue);
  }
}
```

En general una función con el nombre `onEdit` se dispara cada vez que se edita una celda y recibe un evento `e` que guarda información sobre la hoja activa y la celda que se editó.

Lo primero es obtener las hojas de tu documento que deseas conectar. En este caso la `hoja 1` y la `hoja 2`. Luego seleccionas la hoja activa y el valor que introdujo el usuario.

Se filtran las dos celdas conectadas con dos `if`, que básicamente preguntan:

- Si lo que se modificó fue `A1` de la
  `hoja 1`, pon este valor en `A1` de la
  `hoja 2`.
- Si lo que se modificó fue `A1` de la `hoja 2`, pon este valor en
  `A1` de la `hoja 1`.

Eso es todo. Te recuerdo finalmente que en `Google Sheets` el código de scripts se inserta en:
`Herramientas` > `Editor de Secuencia de Comandos`

## Igualando Columnas

En el caso que requieras igualar una columna entera puedes lograrlo con cambios menores en ese script. Te adjunto un pequeño código que puedes usar:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Hojas que deseas conectar
  let hoja1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Hoja 1');
  let hoja2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Hoja 2');
  
  // Hoja activa
  let sheetName =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
  
  if(e.range.getA1Notation()[0] === 'A' && hoja1.getSheetName() == sheetName){
    hoja2.getRange('A:A').setValues(hoja1.getRange('A:A').getValues())
  }

  if(e.range.getA1Notation()[0] === 'A' && hoja2.getSheetName() == sheetName){
    hoja1.getRange('A:A').setValues(hoja2.getRange('A:A').getValues())
  }
}
```

Te adjunto un ejemplo en [google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZBEmgVpX3QdgmurQZnhO1ImGllbLrA1n10MzUarzOZs/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Buenas tardes Jaime, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Funciona perfecto. ¿Habría opcion de aplicarlo tambien a todos los valores de una columna? Que en vez de una celda individual como A1 fuese la columna entera A.
Muchas gracias

Comment: @FelipeJiménezPrieto ahí edité mi respuesta para conectar columnas. Saludos.